# How do I use Reactive in common scenario

Tags: wpf, reactiveui

I'm starting using ReactiveUI in some projects; I still have some difficult to understand some core concepts and I don't know how to manage some common scenario, what are best practices.

Suppose I created a TextEditor which expose a TextChanged event. I manage to create an observable named "CanSave" attached to this event which emit true when user write something;
Now I can use "CanSave" as "canexecute" property of a Save command. This works but, when user click Save, "CanSave" should now emit false because user already saved his work!

How is supposed to manage situations like this? I figured out to create a CanSave settable property and subscribe it to changed event, then observe CanSave property .. is this the correct way?

Comment: The question might open with a wide description but it's about a specific scenario. I don't follow what the problem is with it.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there, or maybe your terminology and description is misleading me.

You need some sort of an Iobservable IsDirty ( or CanSave ) which you can use as a canexecute.

This should be true when a significant change has been made but not saved.

You want to observe TextChanged and set IsDirty to true when that is raised. Maybe also checking something significant happened.

Change it to false when the user saves.

If you somehow make or wrap your IsDirty as an IoBservable you can then just pass it in a factory method like ReactiveCommand.CreateFrom.... for a reactive command.

```
var command = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(LogOnAsync, IsDirty);
```

You could separate stuff by putting say length in other observables.  In which case you'd want to build a canexecute that observes multiple observables using WhenAnyValue.

https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/

A common preference is to work with a property. You then use observable as property helper
The docs tell you to work this way.

https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/observable-as-property-helper/

https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/guidelines/framework/prefer-oaph-over-properties

```
public class RepositoryViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
  public RepositoryViewModel()
  {
    canDoIt = this.WhenAny(x => x.StuffFetched, y => y.OtherStuffNotBusy, (x, y) => x && y)
  .ToProperty(this, x => x.CanDoIt);
  }

  readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> canDoIt;
  public bool CanDoIt
  {
     get { return canDoIt.Value; }  
  } 
}
```

If you think about it, CanDoIt above is fairly similar to what you'd probably want.

Because you'll also want to guard your commands using something like IsBusy so the user can't hit save ( or anything time consuming ) then immediately try to do something else like hit save again whilst it's still doing it's thing.

In my opinion, reactiveui is pretty clever stuff.

But.

You're paying a lot for that functionality in terms of a learning curve and arguably a counter intuitive way of doing things.